# Making a WiFi event recorder

Tags: arduino

I want to make a stomp box with a single button that will record an event time. I’d like the box to be able to record the event directly to a web database (there are plenty of ways to do this, but I’ll probably write a PHP api to listen for the connection).

What hardware would be best? I’ve got experience with the Arduino board, but I ‘d prefer that the box run off AA batteries. My previous Arduino projects have been a bit power-intensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of choosing an Arduino board, use an ESP8266 variant which natively supports Arduino sketches. You can use a relay or directly connect a button to the I/O pins and detect whenever a button is triggered - triggering the server to push the timestamp to a database, increasing the count of the stomp in the database. Instead of writing a PHP application. An easy choice would be to push data to [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) - unless you find this task more tedious.